# How Efficient is DB4o for Android App Development

Tags: android, android-sqlite, db4o

I am looking forward to switch from SQLite to DB4o for My Android Projects, I have a Question.

Q1 .How dose DB4o avoids the data redundancy.

for Example I have two class

```
Class School {

school info 1....

school info 2....

school info n....

}

Class Student {

School mSchool;

Student info 1..

Student info 2..

Student info n..

} 

School newEra=new School("New Era");

Student S1=new Student();

Student S2=new Student();

Student S3=new Student();

Student S4=new Student();

S1.mSchool=newEra;

S2.mSchool=newEra;

S3.mSchool=newEra;

S4.mSchool=newEra;
```

If we save Object `S1,S2,S3,S4` in `DB4o`

since School is a field in Student Class will it be saved multiple time along with `S1,S2,S3,S4`, if No then what happens when we delete  `newEra` from `DB4o` , will it be removed from `S1,S2,S3,S4` also?

Thanks.